# how to make the items of expandable listview check/uncheckable

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have an expandablelistview that works fine. Now I want to export the data of expandable listview and I want the user to be able to choose (or check like there be a checkbox or something) which items of listview to export. How can I do that? Can anyone give me a solution please? I have searched the net but didn't find something useful.

P.S: I have an idea, Can I place a checkbox in explistview rows and set actions to them?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Of course that is possible. Just define such a layout xml file.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps but how can I listen for the actions of the checkbox? In the ExplistAdapter or in the ExplistActivity?

Comment: In the adapter you assign onCheckChanged listeners to the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a normal expandablelistview.
You have to implement the logic yourself in OnChildItemClickListener.

For an example look here: https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/ExpandableListViewWithChoice